# Syntax error at or Near

Tags: postgresql, syntax

I know this will be a forehead slapper. When I highlight and execute my copy command it works fine. However, when I put it in a do statement and execute, I get the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Warner"
```

I looked around and couldn't find an obvious solution. I moved the semi-colon at the end of the do statement, removed it, the error will not go away. Any ideas anyone? Thanks...

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
COPY _tmp_employer_create FROM STDIN;
Warner Bros. Entertainment Inc. Manually Entered    Manually_Entered-Unverified STUDIO
Disney. Entertainment.  Manually Entered    Manually_Entered-Unverified STUDIO
\.
END;
$$
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you use a inline block (DO statement) here? It has no sense. More - inline block is parsed to syntax tree - it means so it is effective disconnected from stdin -  so there is no way, how to use a COPY together with data inside DO statement.

Any access from server side scripts to stdin or stdout is terrible difficult - and on typical level is impossible.

Comment: I have some things going against me. I'm a newbie (to PostgreSQL), the network administrator is out today or else I'd totally do this from a file. But I appreciate you pointing those things out. I'll just have to deal with executing it manually, until Monday (when the network admin gets back).

Comment: if you have some file in CSV format, then use simply COPY statement. Don't use a DO statement. if you can start a console - psql, then you can write - "\copy _tmp_employer_create from pathfile csv"